# Reading data from Firebase to Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am trying to list all data from Javascript keys Object when I put it in console log there is all information, but when I want to use InnerHTML I keep getting the first object only shown.

```
function gotData(data){

  var scores = data.val();
  var keys = Object.keys(scores);

  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var k = keys[i];
    var pro = scores[k].result;
    var doc = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = pro;
  }

}
```

In this case, it will give me only a **result** of first element from my Firebase

Thanks

Comment: At first glance, it looks like you keep reassigning the same element `doc`. When the loop finished its only got the one value, the one you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this [stackblitz-demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gqd9kx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html), looks like your missing one small thing if I am understanding what your expected outcome is.

```js
onClick() {

  const scores = [{
    'one': 1
  }, {
    'two': 2
  }, {
    'three': 3
  }, {
    'four': 4
  }, {
    'five': 5
  }];
  var keys = Object.keys(scores);
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    const k = keys[i];
    const pro = scores[k].result;
    // here the += is what i think you're missing.
    const doc = document.getElementById("example").innerHTML += k;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast respond, in both cases it gives me a list of internal keys of Firebase and no data I want from " results" itself. I managed before to get list of keys shown in HTML.

Comment: @Milos its difficult without the actual response to see what it is your expected vs actual. I suggest adding a screenshot to your question or adding some of the resp. But just guessing here, sounds like you need to pluck those values to separate things you want on the view.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are overriding `innerHTML` each time. Instead, you need to append to the existing `innerHTML`. Change the last line to...

```
const doc = document.getElementById("example").appendChild(document.createTextNode(k))
```

`appendChild` is also much faster than setting `innerHTML`

Comment: Thanks for your fast respond, in both cases it gives me a list of internal keys of Firebase and no data I want from " results" itself. I managed before to get list of keys shown in HTML.

Comment: Sorry, I changed specific value, it wors great ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

`.hasOwnProperty` is how to see just your stored values. Does this help?

```
d = snap.val();
for (var k in d) {
  if (d.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
    if (isObject(d[k]){
      console.log(k, d[k]);
    } else {
      console.log (k);
    }
  }
}
    function isObject(obj) {
        return obj === Object(obj);
    }
```